# titanium sdk "ERROR: Asset package include '/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.3.0.GA/android/titanium.jar' not found"

Tags: android, ubuntu, titanium-alloy

so I started Titanium after a month or so to test a project code. When I am running the code, I am getting

**ERROR: Asset package include '/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.3.0.GA/android/titanium.jar' not found**

I am not sure what is the issue?

Couldn't find anything related to this on Google.

Anyone else faced this? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you developing from root user?

Comment: Yes.. I am doing it from the root

Comment: That could be the problem. Try launching the build from ordinary user

Comment: Same thing... I reinstalled the studio again... now I am getting fatal error and unable to launch titanium studio..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178514/after-update-to-340-ga-nothing-works-any-more#answer-283193) answer fixed it for me. Do not forget to remove the directories under build tools which are above API 20.

It will work.